# VideoJS + HTML5 mp4 video used to work on iOS, now does not (iOS5)

Tags: html, video, ios5

I have a webpage with a bunch of embedded html5 video widgets driven by VideoJS.

It currently works in all major browsers and iOS4, including Windows safari 5.1.7.

with iOS5, the html5 video appears with a play button with a line through it.

playing the video via direct link works just fine in iOS5, but the embedded versions show up with that play button crossed out...

Anyone know what the deal is with new iOS that prevents HTML5 mp4 videos from no longer playing back?

iOS4 safari play the embedded video as expected...

Comment: I'm having similar problems, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

May be the server which is hosting the video files doesn't support byte-range requests.

Please check whether the hosting server can 206 response code. If it sends that, iOS can play them.

More explanation can be found at : [Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)